# How to pass values of StringBuffer to different Activities using Intent

Tags: android, android-activity, parameter-passing, stringbuffer

Code of `StringBuffer` data:

```
StringBuffer finalbufferdata = new StringBuffer(); 
for (int i = 0; i < parentarray.length(); i++) { 
   JSONObject finalobj = parentarray.getJSONObject(i); 
   String id = finalobj.getString("student_id"); 
   String name = finalobj.getString("first_name"); 
   String m_name = finalobj.getString("middle_name"); 
   String l_name = finalobj.getString("last_name");   
   finalbufferdata.append(id+" "+name+" "+m_name+" "+l_name+"\n"); 
}
```

Comment: (You do have a `StringBuilder`: use `finalBufferData.append(finalobj.getString("student_id")).append(' ').append(finalobj.getString("first_name")).append(`…) (`StringBuffer`? Do you _need_ synchronisation?)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it really depends on what your goal is. You could just pass along the `String` like this (This is my preferred way):

```
StringBuffer finalbufferdata = new StringBuffer();
....
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("YOUR_KEY_HERE", finalbufferdata.toString());
```

If you really needed it, `StringBuffer` implements `Serializable` and `CharSequence` so you should just be able to pick one and add that directly to the intent like so:

```
StringBuffer finalbufferdata = new StringBuffer();
....
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("YOUR_KEY_HERE", (Serializable) finalbufferdata);
```

If you are more specific about what you need, I may be able to help more.

Comment: thanx but how can i retrieve the data  from the string builder in the second activity

Comment: If you are passing a String: in your new activity, use `getIntent().getStringExtra("YOUR_KEY_HERE");`